# win32com not importing from python file - DLL load failed

Tags: python, error-handling, win32com

I'm trying to import win32com.client module into python 2.7.10 which give me error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/varma/Desktop/1.py", line 2, in <module>
        import win32api
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

But the same is working from Python Shell and terminal and not giving any error if i execute code

```
import win32com.client
```

[image: Code running in Sheel not giving any error]

Why running the code giving in python file giving me error and the same code is not giving any error if wrote on terminal and shell ?
[image: Error While running code from python file]

Comment: In the shell, try `import win32com`, then just `win32com`. Where does it say `win32com` is coming from?

Comment: The code is working fine in shell but same code is not working if i execute it from Python file

Comment: Yep - you said that already. We're trying to find out why one is working and the other isn't. When you're running from a script, it's getting `win32com` from `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com`, which is causing it issues. When you run from shell, we don't know where it comes from. It might be coming from a different file, which might be why it works when the other doesn't. It might be coming from the same file, in which case we'll need to keep digging.

Comment: I found win32, win32com, win32comext total 3 folders @ C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages Path

Comment: #1 - Start your Python shell. #2 - Type `import win32com; win32com` and press return. #3 - Post the output as a comment on this question.

Comment: I suppose you have multiple _Python_ "installations" on your computer (whether they are explicitly installed or implicitly - by other apps). Any env vars (e.g. _PYTHONHOME \ PYTHONPATH_) set? Also , besides previous comment, the output of `import sys, os; print sys.path, os.environ` would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

The below command in batch file for Anaconda installation worked for me.

"C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\condabin\activate" && python "script.py" && deactivate

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32556017)