# win32api will import via Python CLI, but throws DLL error when actually in a program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I apologize as it seems this question has certainly been asked before.  I have searched and scrounged through any answer I can find, and I just can't figure this out.

I am trying to use win32api as per this guide I am following, but I am having trouble getting it to work.  If I "import win32api" from the Python command line, it doesn't give me any errors.  If I try to use it as an import in the actual program though, I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 7, in 
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

win32con is also listed and that will import fine if I comment out win32api.

The biggest solution through most of the pages I have found are that this usually occurs when you are mis-matching 32 and 64 bit DLLs with the opposite Python.  I have purposely uninstalled pywin32 and reinstalled to verify I was installing the 32-bit version.  I am using the 32-bit version of Python 2.7, and have even uninstalled and reinstalled this today as well.  I tried installing ActivePython as well.

I am new to all of this, and even getting this far has proven to be somewhat of a nightmare, trying to follow old instructions or just bits and pieces being slightly off here and there. I can generally figure out what I need to do to solve computer issues, but this one is stumping me and it's really starting to frustrate me.

Thank you for any suggestions that I maybe haven't tried yet.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 7, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

and

```
<module 'win32api' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\win32api.pyd'>
```

and

```
<module 'win32con' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32con.pyc'>
```

Comment: This is a dupe of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470227/win32com-not-importing-from-python-file-dll-load-failed

Comment: Two things. #1 - Give us the stack trace from the DLL error in the program. #2 - Run `import win32api; win32api` inside the Python CLI, and tell us what it says. I suspect that it's going to end up pointing to two separate files.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - Thank you for the replies so far.  I added the requested information to the original post.  I apologize for the duplicate, but I don't think I see an answer in that post either, similarly to the other posts I had found about this. I've tried what I've found so far, but I'm also really new to this and probably just screwing something up.

Comment: import win32process, win32con, win32api #all 3 at once may help

Comment: @Marichyasana Just tried your suggestion, but the errors show up exactly the same way.  Thank you though